# Customizing form_post response view in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 and I'd like to add some kind of simple visual loading indicator when a user is being authorized/redirected using "form_post" response mode.

When the connect/authorize route is called with a "form_post" response mode, it returns a blank page with a form that submits, so I'm trying to figure out how to add some custom html to this page.

[I found this issue for IdentityServer3 that covers my exact use case](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2124) but I'm not finding how to implement this in IdentityServer4 as it doesn't use the ViewService structure that 3 uses.

I started down the path of a custom authorize interaction response generator but If I redirect to a custom view from here but I'm not sure what that custom view needs to look like to handle the form posting part of the process.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator : AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator
{
    //...

    public override async Task<InteractionResponse> ProcessInteractionAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request, ConsentResponse consent = null)
    {
        var interactionResponse = await base.ProcessInteractionAsync(request, consent);

        if (interactionResponse.IsLogin ||
            interactionResponse.IsError ||
            interactionResponse.IsConsent)
        {
            return interactionResponse;
        }

        if (request.ResponseMode == "form_post")
        {
            return new InteractionResponse
            {
                RedirectUrl = "/custom_form_post"
            };
        }

        return interactionResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to customize the HTML on this redirect page?

Comment: @ToreNestenius sometimes depending on network conditions or what you're being redirected to, you can spend several seconds on this blank page. Particularly if a process kicks this off in a new tab, it can be confusing for users

Answer (score 1):

That page is hardcoded in IdentityServer and the code for it is located in the [AuthorizeResult.cs](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Endpoints/Results/AuthorizeResult.cs) class.

So I guesss customizing it will be hard unless you recompile IdentityServer yourself.

Another option could perhaps be to customize the consent-screen and display something to the user, before that page is returned.

Comment: Are you happy with my answer or are there something missing? If not, please mark my answer as accepted.